# Reflected XSS in form action - understanding

Tags: xss, password-reset, reflected-xss

I am trying to learn basics of web security vulnerabilities.

I have found a website, where on reset password, you get a link in the email with a token, and when you click this link, the webpage opens and the url is reflected in a form action. Something like this:

password reset url: `https://target.com/token=q123sefgetrt3dfe`

and this is how it is reflected:

```
<form action="https://target.com/toekn=q123sefgetrt3dfe" method="post">
```

Based on this, i am trying to figure out if this can lead to reflected XSS. So in the url i tried something like this:

```
https://target.com/token=q123sefgetrt3dfe"/><script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

so that the form tag is closed, and a script is inserted inside the form.

This reflects in the form action, but with url encoded, so quotes are turned to %22 and angular brackets to %3E.

Does this mean that reflected xss can't be achieved here?
is the browser encoding this , or the web page itself must be encoding this ?
is there a way to bypass to see if there is a vulnerability?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that reflected xss can't be achieved here?

The xss can not be achieved here because the context of outbound encoding(URL encoding) is correct which means URL encoding is applied to data reflecting in the URL and as owasp suggests, the outbound encoding is one of the solution for XSS vulnerability.

CSP and xss auditors in browser also plays a role in preventing xss.